# how to pass data from UIPageViewController to child ViewController using delegates

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols, uipageviewcontroller

I want to pass data from a `UIPageViewController` to one of its child `ViewControllers`.
I have a protocol set like so:

```
protocol Delegate : class{
    func protocolMethod(count:Int)
}
```

And in `UIPageViewController`:

```
class PageVC : UIPageViewController{
    var delegate : Delegate?
    var count : Int = 1

    func classMethod(){
        self.displayPageForIndex(5) //this controlls the tranistion to the child ViewController 
        self.delegate?.protocolMethod(count : self.count) 
    }
}
```

In the conforming child `ViewController`:

```
class ChildVC : UIViewController , Delegate{

    func protocolMethod(count : Int){
        print(count)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() { 
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let pvc = PageVC()
        pvc.delegate = self
    }
}
```

What I've done in `viewDidLoad` is the most simplistic solution I've tried, but still couldn't find the answer as to how to let the `PageViewController` know that the child `ViewController` is the receiver of the protocol method.
If anyone could help me accomplish that without using prepareForSegue (as there are no segues) it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Where is your `ChildVC` and `PageVC` instantiated? Also, I would recommend having a name for your delegate that specifies what it does or is used for.

Comment: i have a function that instantiates the child VCs and then i add them to an array. the PageVC itself is not instantiated (well, the functionality of the PageViewController works perfectly so maybe its instantiated in a different way then the child vcs).  the names here are just place holders for me to get the idea of what should be done, i use specific names in my real code @toddg

Comment: "the PageVC itself is not instantiated" Clearly there's a knowledge gap here about what a class and instance is, and how instances get made in iOS / Cocoa programming. There's nothing more basic: one can't do object-oriented programming unless one knows about objects.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
    let pvc = PageVC()
```

That makes a *new, separate* PageVC. That's not what you want. You want a reference to the *existing, actual* PageVC whose parent this is. That reference is `self.parent` (though not, perhaps, in `viewDidLoad`, which is rather early and might not guarantee that we are the child yet).

Answer (score 0):

If your child view controller knows that it's always going to be in the context of a `UIPageViewController` then you can use the parent/child links in the view controllers to allow those controllers to discover one another and exchange data.  Particularly useful in those situations are the methods in the **Responding to Containment Events** section of the `UIViewController` class reference.

If you want to use a protocol then I would define the protocol on the page view controller and pass that protocol to the child view controller when I create it.  So:

```
protocol MyDataSourceProtocol {
  func gimmeSomeData() -> Data
}

// The UIPageViewController implements MyDataSourceProtocol because
// he's going to provide information to his children.
class PageVC : UIPageViewController, MyDataSourceProtocol {
  func gimmeSomeData() -> Data {
      ...
  }

  func makeChildViewControllers() -> ChildViewControllers {
      return childControllerElements.map {
        element : ChildControllerElement in

        // pass self to let the child view controller know I'll be his
        // source
        return ChildViewController(self)
      }
  }
}
```

And then make sure your child view controller knows were to get stuff

```
class ChildViewController : UIViewController {
  let dataSource : MyDataSourceProtocol
  init(dataSource : MyDataSourceProtocol) {
    self.dataSource = dataSource
  }
}
```

Finally some comments on style:

You'll want to be careful with the term "delegate" as it has a very specific meaning in the context of Cocoa APIs and your use here does not match that meaning.  Also naming a class with a lower case letter (childVC) is poor style.